# Any relationship for repeated results for tossed coin?

Tags: statistics

I tossed coin (fair) 10 times and collected data as follows:-
H
H
T
H
H
T
H
T
H
H
what I did added "repeat" in  observation if previous toss was same; like 
H    (Repeat)
H
T
H    (Repeat) 
H
T
H
T
H    (Repeat)
H
 "(Repeat)"  if last toss is same to previous results;  could I establish any relationship between these two observations that next "Repeat" happens would be for T? 
Thanks in advance,
Anoop, Sydney

Answer (score 1):

No, the point is that each new toss will be completely uncorellated to the previous ones. The exact situation you describe was analysed deeply [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy#An_example:_coin-tossing). The point is that you know the tosses tend to 50%-50%, but their difference does not converge at all.

The wikipedia image brings it to the point:

[image]

The ratio of the tosses will converge but their difference won't, you cannot say anything about the next toss when knowing the previous ones.